# Does CBT have similar IDE integration issues as SBT that require recreating the IDE project from scratch?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, cbt

With SBT’s IntelliJ integration, my project often gets in a state where it’s necessary to do the following:

1. Invalidate caches and restart
2. If that doesn’t work, delete the `.idea` directory and “Creat project from existing sources”

Does CBT’s IntelliJ integration have the same problem?

Comment: I don't have an answer for CBT but have you tried using the SBT shell in Intellij? I've found it much better.

Comment: Yes the SBT shell doesn’t prevent the need to recreate the project.

Comment: Pity. The reason that used to happen for me was if I did sbt things on the command line outside Intellij.

Comment: If you have any reproducible way to trigger this problem please report it on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL